# Dynamic slider value changing in javascript

Tags: javascript, listener

I have a slider, and currently, once it is dragged and dropped, it changes the value of a textbox and a span element. I'd like it to change it as I am sliding, but it only changes after I slide it and let go of the slider. Is there an event listener that would make this work?

Currently I have

```
document.getElementById("slider").addEventListener("change", slideChange);
```

and the function:

```
function slideChange() {
    var newDog = document.getElementById("slider").value;
    document.getElementById("desired").value = newDog;
}
```

Comment: Try [`input` event](http://jsfiddle.net/a1owf47c/)

Comment: That seems to have worked thanks a lot!!